# If each term of a $3\times3$ matrix $A$ constructed by selecting a number from the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ with the same probability $1/3$, then ...

Tags: probability, matrices

This is a multiple select question, that is more than one options can be correct:

> If each term of a $3\times3$ matrix $A$ constructed by selecting a number from the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ with the same probability $1/3$, then
>
> 1. The probability that trace $A$ is greater than zero is more than $1/3$.
> 2. The probability that $A$ is a diagonal matrix is less than $1/81$.
> 3. The probability that $A$ is a non-singular lower triangle matrix is more than $1/81$.
> 4. The probability that $A$ is symmetric is less than $1/81$.

My try:

1. Trace can be greater than zero if diagonal is any arrangement of $(1,0,0)$ or any arrangement of $(1,1,0)$ or any arrangement of $(1,1,1)$ or any arrangement of $(-1,1,1)$, hence possible diagonals are 3+3+1+3=10, hence there are $3^6\cdot10$ matrices with positive trace. So, probability is $\frac{3^6(10)}{3^9}$.
2. This is $\frac{3^3}{3^9}$.
3. All the entries above diagonal zero, the diagonal can take only 1 or -1, and below diagonal entries can be any of 1, -1, 0. So, $\frac{2^33^3}{3^9}$ is probability.
4. This is $\frac{3^6}{3^9}$.

Am I correct above?
Also, where do we use the fact that we are 'selecting a number from the set {−1,0,1} with the same probability 1/3'?

Comment: You are implicitly using *"selecting a number from the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ with the same probability $1/3$"* in your counting calculations since you treat each possibility as equally likely

Comment: In addition to assuming that each number is equally likely, you are also implicitly assuming that the selections are independent, which should be listed as an assumption in the problem statement, but isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, where do we use the fact that we are 'selecting a number from the set {−1,0,1} with the same probability 1/3'?

You are using this implicitly by calculating the probabilities as the ratio of "allowed matrices" to "possible matrices" where you construct these matrices with the three elements occurring equally likely. This method only works if all the individual outcomes are equally likely.

> Am I correct above?

I think your calculations are correct. Simplifying the probabilities will allow you to compare more easily with the given probability thresholds in the answers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Where should I make change in calculations if I am given that e.g., $-1,1,0$ is selected with some other probability like $0.2,0.5,0.3$ respectively?

Comment: I'll pick an easy one to illustrate: the probability that $A$ is diagonal then comes down to having zeroes off the diagonal (6 spots), so that happens with probability $0.3^6$ (compared to $\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right)^6$ now).